# How to format a getUpdatedAt() kind of date in Symfony?

Tags: php, date, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'd like to change the formatting of a date in Symfony 1.4

The default one being:

```
<?php echo $question->getUpdatedAt(); 
// Returns 2010-01-26 16:23:53
?>
```

I'd like my date to be formatted like so: `26/01/2010 - 16h23`

I tried using the `format_date` helper `DateHelper` class.

Unfortunately the [API](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/DateHelper) is rather empty (something really needs to be done about it.)

Browsing the helper's source code, I found that a second argument, format, can be passed.

I assumed it was using the same syntax as [PHP's date function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php).
But here's what it outputs (same example as above):

```
<?php sfContext::getInstance()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers('Date');
// [...]
 echo format_date($question->getUpdatedAt(),'d/m/y - H\hi')
// Returns 26/23/2010 - 16\4i
```

I'm sure I'm not the first one having trouble doing this but I've been Googling around and nothing accurate showed up.

Do you guys have any idea how to format a date in Symfony 1.4?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have a look at the [new functions in 1.4](http://www.symfony-project.org/tutorial/1_4/en/whats-new#chapter_a2fae23c9403b0e9ec99806fccf6b53e_sub_date_setters_and_getters).

You can do:

```
$question->getDateTimeObject('updated_at')->format('d.m.Y');
// I assume the field's name is 'updated_at'
```

From the docs:

> **Date Setters and Getters**
>
> We've added two new methods for retrieving **Doctrine** date or timestamp values as PHP DateTime object instances.
>
> ```
> echo $article->getDateTimeObject('created_at')->format('m/d/Y');
> ```
>
> You can also set a dates value by simply calling the setDateTimeObject method and passing a valid DateTime instance.
>
> ```
> $article->setDateTimeObject('created_at', new DateTime('09/01/1985'));
> ```

But it seems only to work for Doctrine.

Answer (score 1):

How bout going with the default PHP date function? `date('d/m/Y', strtotime($question->getUpdatedAt())`

Comment: I'd prefer using the format_date helper, do you know what keywords the format parameter is using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use also sfDateFormat class to work with dates.
[link text](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfDateFormat#method_format)

Answer (score -3):

do you try :

```
echo $question->getUpdatedAt('d/m/y - H\hi')
```

I think it's the easiest way